# How to copy artifacts from downstream jobs to top level job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a Jenkinsfile that has following steps

```
    stage"xyzclientj_maven_common"
    build job: 'xyzclientj_maven_common', propagate: true, parameters:
    [
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
    ],


    parallel (
      "multios" : {
        build job: 'ccsmp_tag_multios', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },

      "OpenVms-ia64" : {
        build job: 'ccsmp_tag_OpenVms-ia64', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },

      "win_platform" : {
        build job: 'ccsmp_tag_win_platform', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },

      "iphoneOS_176" : {
        build job: 'ccsmp_tag_iphoneOS_176', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },

      "epoll-linux26-x64" : {
        build job: 'ccsmp_tag_epoll-linux26-x64', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },

      "android" : {
        build job: 'android', parameters:
        [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SVN_TAG', value: env.SVN_TAG],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: env.VERSION]
        ],
        propagate: true
      },
      failFast: false
    )
```

Is there any way to achieve and copy the artifacts made by these downstream jobs to my top level multibranch pipeline job.

( *Some background details- So I have a top level branch agnostic multibranch pipeline job called ccsmp and It uses my Jenkinsfile to trigger downstream jobs, some of these jobs are sequential and also parallel. These jobs produce artifacts and I don't know how to achieve and copy these artifacts produced by these jobs to my top level job. I just cant wrap my head around this.*)

Please help me any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // trigger the other job and wait for it to complete
    final job_result = build job: 'TheOtherJob', 
        wait: true, 
        parameters: [
             string(name: 'NAME1', value: "value1"), // etc.
        ]

    // get downstream job build number
    def downstream_job_number = "${job_result.number}"

    // copy artifact of the other job to this workspace
    // provided by a Jenkins Plugin
    def path_to_artifact = 'my_file.txt'
    step([
        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
        filter: path_to_artifact,
        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
        optional: true,
        projectName: "TheOtherJob",
        selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                    buildNumber: downstream_job_number]
    ])

    // you can read that artifact now
    def artifact_text = readFile file: path_to_artifact
    println artifact_text

    // or archive it as your job artifact
    archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true,
        artifacts: "${path_to_artifact}",
        caseSensitive: false, defaultExcludes: false, onlyIfSuccessful: true
```

Comment: Hi Thank you soooooo much for your answer I highly appreciate it. Just a small doubt, do I have to repeat this step for every job, as I have multiple sequential and parallel jobs, so do I have to repeat this for every downstream job that I have??